# How many people do you have in your city? How many people are there in your city?

Tags: grammar

> How many people do you have in your city?

> How many people are there in your city?

Is there a grammatical difference? I heard both many times. But once I came across a book, where "do you have" sentence was considered wrong. Don't understand why.

Comment: Your first sentence is perfectly grammatical, and perfectly understandable, it's just something that native English speakers wouldn't say in normal circumstances. They might say that about public facilities - _How many parks/concert halls/pubs do you have in your city?_- but not about people.

Comment: "Do you have...." would be understood by most listeners but is a little awkward, because it sounds just a little bit like the listener is in charge of the city or somehow was involved with getting the people there.  Better: "Are there many people in your city?"

Comment: Oh, @ColinFine makes a good point and his comment crossed mine in time.  I don't know why his example about places sounds correct, and the one with people does not.  But he's correct:  "Do you have many parks in your city?" is totally natural.  Perhaps "<pronoun> + has" prompts us to think about property, and the fact that people cannot be property makes a cognitive dissonance that resolves via the extra connoted meaning I indicate in my first comment.

Comment: "What is the [**population**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/population) of your city?"

Answer (score 2):

This is simpler to explain with statements (or answers) rather than questions.

- I have a million people in my city.

Unless I’m talking about a game, I don’t “have” those million people in the sense of ownership or possession, so this isn’t right.

- We have a million people in our city.

This isn’t as bad, but it’s still odd to say those million people have ownership or possession of themselves.

- You have a million people in your city.

“You” here could be singular or plural, but as in both cases above, neither works.

- There are a million people in the city.

“There is/are” is used to simply say things exist, without the sense of ownership or possession that “have” brings, so this works well here. Note that is/are agrees with the thing that follows:

- There is one dog.
- There are two dogs.

Native speakers think of “there is/are” as a special construction with its own rules (like “hay” in Spanish and “il-y-a” in French), but you could also think of these as being normal grammar that is just said backwards:

- One dog is there.
- Two dogs are there.